# Is there an equivalent to the cases environment for proofs?

Tags: math-mode, theorems, cases, proof-package

The cases environment is nice for displaying equations with multiple cases and short descriptions, but it is awkward for displaying proofs with multi-paragraph cases. Is there an equivalent set of tags more like the HTML <dl>, <dt> and <dd> tags? Something like

```
\begin{proofcases}
\case Description of first case
\item Proof of first case.
\case Description of second case
\item Proof of second case.
\end{proofcases}
```

I'd like output something like

```
Then 

Foo is a bar. This description is long, cumberome and unieldy if it
has to be displayed using cases.  
     Baz is a blivit. This follows by the covering homotopy theorem. We
     don't need no stinking fiber bundles, and this proof is already too
     long. 
Foo is a widget 
     Baz is a descending chain. This follows because Cuius rei
     demonstrationem mirabilem sane detexi hanc marginis exiguitas non
     caperet. Apologies to Fermat.
```

which is produced by

```
Then
<dl>
<dt>Foo is a bar.
This description is long, cumberome and unieldy if it has to be displayed
using cases. 
<dd>Baz is a blivit.
This follows by the covering homotopy theorem. 

We don't need no stinking fiber bundles, and this proof is already too long.
<dt>Foo is a widget
<dd>Baz is a descending chain.
This follows because Cuius rei demonstrationem mirabilem sane detexi hanc
marginis exiguitas non caperet. Apologies to Fermat.
</dl>
```

The description environment is not suitable because the label is not wrapped. The following examples runs off to the right:

```
\begin{description}
\item%
  [
    This is an example of a very long label for an item of the
    description environment, running over multiple lines, in order
    to demonstrate why it is awkward to use that environment for
    cases of a proof.
  ]
  This is sample text for the description of a case with a long
  label, again running over multiple lines.
\item[short label] short description
\end{description}
```

Comment: Can you please add a picture showing the desired ouptut?

Comment: It often ends up as a waste of space doing proofs like that, especially if the item proofs are long. For some manuscripts I've used a modified `\paragraph ` command (having it have space after it) to make the case stand out, and then write the proof of the case as normal text.

Comment: You can nest list environments 4 deep.  Note the description environment in particular.

Comment: The description environment is nice for short item labels, but awkward for long labels.I

Comment: How is it awkward, exactly?

Comment: Limiting lines of the description label to, e.g., 72 characters, requires adding comment characters (%) to indicate continuation.

Comment: See the edit to the question.  The label runs off to the right instead of wrapping.